# How to wire a standard switch from a dimmer switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I’m replacing my dimmer switch with a standard switch. I have a black, white and ground wires coming out of the wall. Some of these wires were somehow tied together but I don’t recall how.

Comment: Any chance of getting a picture of the switch box?

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the wiring in the wall?